# Connecting WiFi printer using IP address on Android

Tags: java, android, wifimanager

How can i connect to WiFi printer using IP address on Android?

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly but I think that java socket class will help you. WifiManager is only to configur wifi on device. You should simple create socket class and send data.

Comment: If you wait 5 months to answer a question, the person probably won't be looking at it anymore! Try to answer some newer questions.